# Nginx HTTPS www to non-www redirect issue

Tags: nginx, https

I'm having some issues redirecting from HTTPS www to HTTPS non-www with my nginx config.  I'm following the directions provided at ([Remove "www" and redirect to "https" with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/258378/remove-www-and-redirect-to-https-with-nginx)).

Right now the following work:

- http://www.redemfit.com -> https://redemfit.com
- http://redemfit.com -> https://redemfit.com
- https://redemfit.com

But this doesn't:

- https://www.redemfit.com -> https://redemfit.com

I end up getting the "Welcome to nginx!" page.  I don't have any other nginx config files in `/sites-enabled` either.  Any ideas why it might be doing this?

My config file is below.

```
upstream redemfit {
    server unix:/srv/redemfit/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    www.redemfit.com redemfit.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://redemfit.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/redemfit-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/redemfit.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    server_name www.redemfit.com
    rewrite ^ https://redemfit.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen   443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/redemfit-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/redemfit.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

    server_name redemfit.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /srv/redemfit/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /srv/redemfit/logs/nginx-error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /static {
        auth_basic off;
        root /srv/redemfit/static_collected;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://redemfit;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing HTTPS `server {}` block for [www.redemfit.com](http://www.redemfit.com) completely and add the code bellow into main HTTPS block:

```
if ($host = 'www.redemfit.com' ) {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://redemfit.com/$1  permanent;
}
```

I hope while writing the post you made a typo:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/redemfit-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/redemfit.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    server_name www.redemfit.com # <- Missing semicolon
    rewrite ^ https://redemfit.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution for a couple of reasons. 1) Do not use `rewrite` when you are able to issue a redirect using `return` directive (for this solution it will be `return 301 https://redemfit.com$request_uri;`) to avoid an expensive PCRE library call. 2) This one will use a normalized URI to generate the `Location` HTTP header contents which may be a security flaw in some cases (see the _Usage of `$uri` can lead to CRLF Injection_ chapter of the [Common Nginx misconfigurations](https://blog.detectify.com/2020/11/10/common-nginx-misconfigurations/) article.

Comment: Generally due to the performance considerations (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72615689/7121513)) using three server blocks (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970218/7121513)) is the best approach anyway.