# Redirect to https on lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

Trying to understand how to make the redirect to redirect all `http` traffic to `https` on `lighttpd` webserver using `301`.

For instance `http://www.example.com` should redirect to `https://www.example.com` and it should work for all sub pages as it's basically rewrite to `https`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove "www" and redirect to "https" with nginx](http://serverfault.com/questions/258378/remove-www-and-redirect-to-https-with-nginx)

Comment: @Roman That question is about nginx, this question is not.

Comment: @kasperd: Thanks for highlighting, retracted vote accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

After some additional search I found a solution. Added to `lighttpd.conf` restarted and everything works as expected.

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
# capture vhost name with regex conditiona -> %0 in redirect pattern
# must be the most inner block to the redirect rule
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a typo because you wrote from `http://mydomain` should redirect to `http://mydomain`, I think you mean to `https://mydomain`.

I hope this will help you. I have used this Information for my NGINX Webserver:

[HSTS on Lightpttd](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_for_Apache_NGINX_and_Lighttpd.html#Lighttpd) - Turtorial