# HSTS with canonical URL redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx, hsts

I was using the nginx configuration [taken from this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/258378/remove-www-and-redirect-to-https-with-nginx/258424#258424) to implement redirect from http://(www.)example.com -> https://example.com:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    <possibly other ssl directives if you have a separate cert and key for www>
    server_name www.example.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/server.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;
    server_name example.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    <locations for processing requests>
}
```

I'd like to add HSTS to this, so am following the [nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/), which amounts to adding

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
```

to both SSL server blocks (as done above).

TLDR: Is the STS header in the second server block necessary?

However I was doing some reading around the topic, especially [this blog post](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-canonical-www-redirects) which seemed to think that:

> ...if your canonical URL is www.example.com, the includeSubDomains token will not protect example.com as this is not a subdomain of www.example.com. A solution is to make a request from www.example.com to an uncached resource on `https:// example.com`, e.g. a 1px image, and make sure that https:// example.com sets the HSTS header.

I guess this is correct, as if you go straight to canonical `https://www.example.com` then it will only protect `http://*.www.example.com.`

However this doesn't appear an issue if your canonical URL is `https://example.com` and you use `includeSubDomains`. I tested it on Chrome and it did the following `http://www.example.com` (307) -> `https://www.example.com` (301) -> `https://example.com`.

So is the `Strict-Transport-Security` header in the second `listen 443 ssl` `www.example.com` block necessary? As a direct request to `https://www.example.com` would be SSL anyway, and it would pick up the STS `includeSubDomains` header on redirect from the third server block, protecting `http://www.example.com` in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is preferred to have the STS header in both `server` blocks, for the reason you wrote in your question.

Looking at it the other way, there is no harm in specifying the header in the `example.com` server either.

Comment: I don't think it will validate for preloading _unless_ it is in the `example.com`, as well as subdomains

Comment: What do you mean by preloading here?

Comment: HSTS preloading is where browsers hard code the URLs of HSTS sites into the browser, thereby ensuring that there is NEVER a non-HTTPS communication with the site. In order to be included, the HSTS header must be included on the base domain. Here is the [`hstspreload.org` landing page](https://hstspreload.org/) with more details.

Comment: Also, preloading will require that `http://example.com` (HTTP) immediately redirect to `https://example.com` (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain, that is, before redirecting to `https://www.example.com`. The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.

Comment: All of this, of course, is only relevant if the `preload` header is desired, which is why it is just offered as a comment to your answer. Although not presently preventing an A+ rating, Qualys' SSL Server Test is now at least checking for preloading.

Comment: @Colt The `preload` will be required eventually. I was looking through the hstspreload.org site and it seemed to answer my question: "If you are serving an additional redirect from your HTTPS site, that redirect must still have the HSTS header (rather than the page it redirects to)." So the header in server #2 stays.

Comment: That is correct. In addition to being required to make the two-step redirect described above, the only other caveat is that an HTTP "site" that exists just to redirect to the HTTPS version shoud NOT have the header. You can also use the `hstspreload.org` site to "test" your setup. As long as you don't have `preload` directive set it will not attempt to submit your site, but it will tell you _exactly_ what you need to do to be compliant (including later adding the `preload` directive).

Comment: Thanks @Colt for the information, I didn't know the details of preloading, only that the mechanism exists. I have to keep it in mind with future projects.

Comment: I think adding the quote"If you are serving an additional redirect from your HTTPS site, that redirect must still have the HSTS header (rather than the page it redirects to)." and a link to hstspreload.org  would enhance the answer.